# result.responseXML is undefined on ajax getItems from Sharepoint list call

Tags: ajax, web-services, sharepoint, caml

I'm working on a script to get some items from a Sharepoint list with ajax. I've been trying to get this working for two weeks now. Although I've done this before, successfuly, on this one I don't know what I am missing.

This is my code:

```
var xmlData ="<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>CACF25CF-D392-4A28-A2C6-91D4C72AEE05</listName><query><Query   xmlns=''><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ows_LinkTitle' /><Value Type='Text'>";
xmlData+=value;
xmlData+="</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query></GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

The *value* variable contains the value to filter the list by.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({   
url: "https://mysharepointsite.net/sites/scm/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",   
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",   
data: xmlData,    
complete:SuccessFuncDetails,   
error: ErrorFunc,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""  
});
```

As I said in the title, the XML response from this call is undefined and I don't know why. I've connected to the list via Sharepoint web services using u2u CAML builder and worked fine.

Also, when I try to debug the script with IE Developer Tools, the script appears blue, like a text or a comment would, and I can't put a breakpoint, although the script executes.

Has anyone any idea why all this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The SOAPAction HTTP header is missing from your request, you can add it by setting it in beforeSend:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mysharepointsite.net/sites/scm/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: xmlData,
    complete: SuccessFuncDetails,
    error: ErrorFunc,  
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListContentTypes'); },
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
```

I also had to modify your query string somewhat, make sure you adapt it to your list:

```
var xmlData = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>{823F6320-4698-4CED-B86A-5929A765CCAF}</listName><viewName /><query><Query   xmlns=''><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /><Value Type='Text'>"; 
xmlData+=value; 
xmlData+="</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query><viewFields><ViewFields xmlns=''><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit>1000</rowLimit><queryOptions><QueryOptions xmlns=''><ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' /></QueryOptions></queryOptions></GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

If you have the web request working in another tool, you can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to compare the output.

The SharePoint server error logs do sometimes give pointers to what is going wrong.

I assume you're workig with SharePoint 2007, if you're only targeting SharePoint 2010, you may be better off using either the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185006) or the [REST services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587) from Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I modified the query and also added the header but it's still not working. I am working with Sharepoint 2007 but I have no access to the server. Is there another way to see the error logs from the sharepoint site?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you look with Fiddler (or Firebug's Net tab if you're using that) at the request and response?

Comment: Hey!Sorry for the big delay.I've been working on another project until now. I've checked with fiddler and it show me that the service could not be found. The result is 404. Any idea why? I mention once again that with CAML builder all runs fine. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Now I'm getting result 500, Exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException was thrown.Value cannot be null.

Comment: You should carefully compare the http request generated by CAML builder (assuming you're using it with the webservice) and that of your JS script. Something must be different...

Comment: The problem disappeared after removing the _beforeSend_ function from the ajax call. When comparing the http requests I also noticed that using the same caml query, the CAML builder returns all the columns from the list while the JS script only returns the columns from the All Items view. Do you know why this happens?